# HTML Signature in iOS Mail

Tags: html, ios, css, email

I am having a problem with the mail app in iOS resizing the image and text of my HTML signature, I have another HTML signature which does not seem to get resized however this one is. When viewed on the iOS mail app the text and images are much larger than they should be. I have tried a various amount of different viewport meta tag variants with no avail.

Here is the HTML code for my email signature:

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body style="word-wrap: break word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space; font-family: Tahoma;">

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" border="0" style="color: #333;" width="480">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="130" rowspan="6" style="width: 1px;"><a href="http://www.unbiased-advice.co.uk/" target="_blank"><img width="130" style="padding-right: 22px; border-right: 1px solid #EEE;" src="http://www.unbiased-advice.co.uk/email-signature/email-logo.gif"/></a></td>
      <td width="350" style="padding: 6px 0 0 13px; font-size: 9pt; color: #444; table-align: left;">Kind Regards,</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 5px 0 6px 13px;"><span style="font-size: 17pt;">Forename Surname</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" style="padding: 0 0 0 13px;"><img src="http://www.unbiased-advice.co.uk/email-signature/ian-hurst-signature.gif" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 6px 0 0px 13px; font-size: 10pt;">01722 123 456 <span style="color: #DDD;">|</span> <a style="color: inherit;" href="mailto:test@test.com">name@unbiased-advice.co.uk</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span style="padding: 6px 0 0px 5px; font-style: italic; font-size: 12px;">"Straight Forward Advice... In Black and White"</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 12px 0 6px 6px; font-size: 10pt;" colspan="2">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/HurstFinancial"><img src="http://www.unbiased-advice.co.uk/email-signature/facebook-logo.gif" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0 5px 0 0; vertical-align: top;"/></a><a style="color: inherit;" href="https://www.facebook.com/HurstFinancial">Facebook</a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/HurstFinancial"><img src="http://www.unbiased-advice.co.uk/email-signature/twitter-logo.gif" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0 5px 0 5px; vertical-align: top;"/></a><a style="color: inherit;" href="https://twitter.com/hurstfinancial">Twitter</a> <span style="color: #DDD;">|</span>
        <a style="color: inherit;" href="http://www.unbiased-advice.co.uk">www.unbiased-advice.co.uk</a>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="padding: 5px 0 1px 6px; font-size: 10pt; color: #555;">35 Chequers Court, Brown Street, Salisbury, Wiltshire, SP1 2AS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 8pt; color: #AAA; padding-top: 12px;">
        <p>Hurst Financial Consultancy Limited is authorised and regulated for investment and mortgage advice by the Financial Conduct Authority Ref 448150.</p>
        <p>Our company registered office is: 35 Chequers Court, Brown Street, Salisbury, Wiltshire, SP1 2AS. Co. Registration Number 5616157.</p>
        <p>We accept no responsibility for the content of any e-mail as internet communications are not necessarily secure.</p>
        <p>Views or opinions presented are those of the author and do not necessarily represent those of Hurst Financial Consultancy Ltd.</p>
        <p>Anyone replying by e-mail to the author of this message (or e-mailing anyone else using the <a style="color: inherit;">anyone@unbiased-advice.co.uk</a> address) is advised that such e-mails may be<br> read by persons other than the intended recipient.</p>
        <p>No responsibility for viruses is assumed but reasonable steps are taken to ensure e-mail is virus free.</p>
        <p>If at any time you would prefer not to receive email from us please <a style="color: inherit;" href="mailto:unsubscribeme@unbiased-advice.co.uk">click here</a> (<a style="color: inherit;">unsubscribeme@unbiased-advice.co.uk</a>) and we will remove your address from future mailings.</p>
      </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If I had to guess...   I would say it's because you are using pt for the font sizes.   Generally, pt should only be used in print media, but never screen media, because of the difference in how DPI can be calculated.   You might try changing to px to see if that helps.

Comment: I did give that try and it unfortunately didn't fix it, the text was a little smaller however the images are still large. When I load the email for the first time as it loading the images you can see it as how it should be displayed then when the images are fully loaded it up scales everything.

Comment: Interesting...  you might also want to specify px for your image widths as well...   I see all your widths are set as `width="150"` without specifying 150 *what*...  I'm not sure what behavior this would cause.   It would be best to specify your widths as `width=150px` to see if this helps resolve the image problem.

Comment: Technically, the use of the `width` tag has been deprecated for some time.   This may also be causing the problem.   Width should really be specified as `style="width:150px"`.

Comment: That's done the trick, I didn't realise it would be using HTML 5 and I've used that width attribute in an img tag on other signatures which is odd. Did you want to post this as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: sure thing...   will do that now haha.   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To fix the font sizes:

Try using `px` instead of `pt`.   The latter is generally used for print media, but may not display correctly on the screen.

### To fix the images:

The `width` tag is currently deprecated.  You can specify width by using CSS, like this:

```
style="width:150px
```